# NumberPicker onValueChange not being called

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hello I'm having some trouble implementing a `DialogFragment` that uses a `NumberPicker`.  I have some code where, if the user presses a button, will prompt the user to select a number through an `AlertDialog`.  I am able to show the `Dialog` fine, but when I select a number through the `Picker`, I cannot save that value.  Based on my debugging, it seems like the `onValueChange` method is never called.  Any ideas why?
Below is my code for my numberPicker `DialogFragment`

```
public static class numberPickerDialog extends DialogFragment
        implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        final NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());
        picker.setMinValue(1);
        picker.setMaxValue(60);
        picker.setValue(25);
        picker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

        builder.setMessage("Set Study Time")
                .setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //cancel
                    }
                });

        final FrameLayout parent = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        parent.addView(picker, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.CENTER));
        builder.setView(parent);

        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        String toastMessage = "test";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach the `OnValueChangeListener` to the NumberPicker.

All you have to do is: `numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(this);`

Comment: @victorydub you might want to select "the best answer" in order to show that this question has been answered and others could learn from it.